# Include PHP statement in genesis function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a Wordpress theme (genesis framework) and i need to input a php snippet into the post meta function (right after post_edit). I cannot seem to get this to work without throwing an error.

This is the function I need to work with:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'sp_post_info_filter' );
function sp_post_info_filter($post_info) {
    $post_info = '[post_date] by [post_author_posts_link] [post_comments] [post_edit]';
    return $post_info;
}
```

And this is the PHP snippet I need to use

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'jetpack-post-views', true ); ?>
```

I'm just not sure where to place it i guess... (I tried right after [post_edit] and got this error)

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /nfs/c08/h04/mnt/152909/domains/genesis.pixelworklab.com/html/wp-content/themes/eleven40-pro/functions.php on line 27
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: @yamikoWebs see error..

Comment: @Shomz that add_filter is line 27. I think this is just a matter of the proper way to insert that snippet into that function. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, that's a syntax error, so I don't think so. What's the line above it?